# aria-label missing when <label for> present in html?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, angular-material, wai-aria, wcag

Following code throws in Chrome console:
ARIA: Attribute " aria-label ", required for accessibility, is missing...

```
<label for="date-range-selector-from">From</label>
<md-input-container>
<input type="text" id="date-range-selector-from" aria-invalid="false" />
...
</md-input-container>
```

Why is it throwing this warning when there is label asociated with input?
Shouldn't be aria-label needed when visible label cannot be shown on the page?

Comment: It might be useful to add the Chrome tag here as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently some "angularjs" code, but Chrome is complaining about your DOM generated code.

You should provide a `label` tag inside the `md-input-container` like in the example provided on the following page: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInputContainer

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>From</label>
  <input type="text" id="date-range-selector-from" aria-invalid="false" />
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: When the label is inside md-input container, then angular's functionality to the label is applied (label is made smaller and moved above the input when input is focused. I just want to have very ordinary label shown within input, no special effects. Thats why I put it outside md-input container. It should be ARIA compatible when I set attribute for and link it with id of the input.

Comment: you have to look at the "md-no-float" option to disable floating label, see link in my answer

Comment: This md-no-float works for placeholder attribute as it is described in material docs, not for label, label is still transformed to animated version eventhough md-no-float is used.